# What would the effects be on the world if light slowed down?

Tags: speed-of-light, physical-constants

It would be really helpful if the effects were just given in a list form so I can research them.

The reason why I am asking this is because I to write an essay regarding the effects of a change in a physical constant. I am currently thinking of writing about either change in gravity or the speed of light. On a side note which topic seems more interesting and easier to write 4000 words on?

Comment: Your essay will be about why there are no effects when a dimensional constant changes.

Comment: You might want to write about what would happen if the fine structure constant got bigger or smaller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to speak about changes in a physical constant which is not dimensionless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78684/)

Comment: Carl Sagan looks funny on his scooter?

Answer (score -3):

For example, less energy will be produced in thermonuclear reactions in the Sun, so the climate on Earth will probably get colder.

Comment: This is wrong, for the reasons given in the answers to the question that this one duplicates.

Comment: @BenCrowell : And I respectfully disagree with those reasons.