# What would it look like if the speed of light in vacuum were to decrease?

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light

I've recently come across theories involving [variable speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light) as a solution for [the Horizon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem) as well as for [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy)'s accelerating expansion of space.

In a discussion with a friend, the idea that a significantly decreased speed of light would make objects appear more distant (the light takes longer to travel to the observer) was presented. I'm not so sure about this, I think objects would appear the same size and shape because they're coming from the same direction as before, only redshifted due to the loss in energy. We also thought about if light experiencing more curvature than before due to being within the gravitational field of large celestial bodies would make them appear in different locations relative to where we currently observe them. Also, perhaps everything would appear a little dimmer, as the light is hitting our eyes with less energy.

In a theoretical alternate reality where the speed of light is half of our measured $c$, and that other constants depending on $c$ have changed proportionally, what visual differences might a human observer from our present reality see, and why? Are the ideas presented above realistic at all or way off? Please note that I'm not interested in a discussion on the validity of the theory above, only what theoretical effects a slower speed of light may have on optics.

If possible, I would greatly appreciate being pointed to resources with formulas for calculating these effects - I have some interest in writing a renderer capable of simulating them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Slower_Speed_of_Light

Comment: @KyleKanos I may be wrong in my understanding, but that game seems like it simulates an observer going close to the speed of light, instead of the perceived constant c actually changing, despite the name. Are they functionally not different?

Comment: Perception of distance has little to do with the time it takes for light to reach our eyes. For any practical scenario, this time would be on the order of nanoseconds, so it's unlikely we can even detect such small time variations. The perception of distance arises from perspective and angles.

Comment: However, different speed of light might lead to effects such as different index of refraction, which could have optical effects similar to those in a glass of water (assuming there is an interface where the speed of light varies).

Comment: You can't detect a change in a dimensionful universal parameter like $c$. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78684/  . Note that warning tag in the section of the WP article you linked to. It's kook stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that it's a nutty theory that isn't currently taken seriously by modern physicists for good reasons. However I'm not interested in debating the specifics of the theory, but merely what it *would* look like to us were $c$ to change significantly.

Comment: It would look like the BIPM, the committee in charge of the SI, made the meter larger. No physics would change, only our units. There is NO physical effect of changing c. The physical constants are the dimensionless ones like the fine structure constant.

Comment: I'm still not quite convinced. I understand that there are nontrivial issues with measuring the change, and that a change would be more easily explained by changes in other constants such that other dimensionless constants are held equal, but if photons literally started moving slower all across the universe, it goes without saying those dimensionless constants derived from $c$ have also changed. Assuming the universe doesn't collapse, I'm interested in the optical effects of photons moving slower, irrespective of possible measurement flaws and problems.

Comment: “it goes without saying those dimensionless constants derived from c have also changed” It doesn’t go without saying. It is critical to state clearly and explicitly in your question. If you intend for a dimensionless constant to change then you need to specify which constant and how much. Otherwise there is no way to ensure that everyone is understanding your question as you intend it. I certainly did not see that was your intention

Comment: "I have some interest in writing a renderer capable of simulating them" $-$ is there some specific reason why you don't want to use the ASSOL engine (MITGameLab's [OpenRelativity](https://github.com/MITGameLab/OpenRelativity)) for this? It solves precisely the problem you're (ostensibly) asking about, and it was developed and open-sourced *precisely* so that other people could use a renderer that does this.

Comment: your question requires two $c$ s-one the human "remembers" the other the changed one. This isn't possible. Anyways, if c were to be too small, you would start seeing cherenkhov everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @lineage, your comment made it very clear that I've been seeking an answer from the perspective of assuming VSL theory is true, yet trying to phrase it in terms of seeking an answer from our current models of physics. I can see why this is a bad question now.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I've been under the impression there would be differences between a slower $c$ under VSL theory and the effects of special relativity that would thus cause different visual effects, perhaps this was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The speed of light is a dimensionful constant and, as such, [**it is impossible to talk about changes to the speed of light**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78684/is-it-possible-to-speak-about-changes-in-a-physical-constant-which-is-not-dimens) without being dead clear about what you *do* want to keep constant.

Your question doesn't really give any meaningful benchmarks for this, so to some extent your question is completely unanswerable.

On the other hand, your emphasis on what it would visually look like to a human does supply an answer to this: define some characteristic speed $v_\mathrm{human}$ that describes your observer's motions, and set *that* as a constant. (In other words: when the speed of light gets slower, does your observer also move slower? Presumably that's not something you want, which points in the direction I've just mentioned. However, it's important to note that it's in direct conflict with your statement that "it goes without saying those dimensionless constants derived from c have also changed", from [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515584/what-would-it-look-like-if-the-speed-of-light-were-to-decrease#comment1162347_515584), because there is no guarantee that the physics that sets $v_\mathrm{human}$ is independent of $c$. This is why your question is ill-posed and not really about physics, but that's neither here nor there.)

The problem posed in that form asks what the world would look like if $c/v_\mathrm{human}$ were smaller, or if $v_\mathrm{human}/c$ were bigger. (Note that the two are completely equivalent, and there is no way to tell them apart.) This problem has been completely solved, and its solution exists:

- as a standalone game, [*A Slower Speed of Light*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Slower_Speed_of_Light), and
- as an open-source toolkit for the Unity engine, [OpenRelativity](https://github.com/MITGameLab/OpenRelativity),

with the latter being the essentials of the back-end for the former. If all you want is the mathematics, so that you can re-implement the code yourself elsewhere, the place to turn to is the sister publication,

- Visualizing relativity: The OpenRelativity project. Z.W. Sherin, R. Cheu and P. Tan. [*Am. J. Phys.* **84**, 369 (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4938057).

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I think I've realized a source of this question's issues - I was implicitly seeking an answer from the perspective of the VSL theory yet trying to frame it in vague terms of physical accuracy under currently accepted theories, which I can see now are fully incompatible. Should I edit my question to make this explicit or ask a new one?

Comment: @Klaycon I'm unlikely to update this answer either way.