# What would happen if the speed of light in vacuum decreased?

Tags: speed-of-light

So,
My question is if the speed of light was decreased, what visual differences will we see? Will it take a long time to see things and for our eyes to capture them? I am not asking for any differences in terms of mass, gravity, etc. but differences in our vision after this happens. I also want to add that what would happen if the speed of light was changed, but everything else stayed the same and no other factor was changed as if they aren't affected by light (like in 3D software and game development.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would it look like if the speed of light were to decrease?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515584/)

Comment: Looks like this question might answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515584/

Comment: @IshaanManish I had already checked it, but it doesn't answer my question.